# RuntimeWarning: coroutine was never awaited

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, discord.py

Been having a lot of trouble lately trying to make my Discord bot simply pull data from Pubg.op.gg and give the user its K/D.

I've been getting multiple errors, but the one that is showing up the most is:

```
F:\Python3\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py:50: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Pubg.get_kd' was never awaited
  ret = yield from coro(*args, **kwargs)
```

From the error messaged I'm just confused on what excatly to await since I can't find Pubg.get_kd.

Heres my code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio,aiohttp,json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

class Pubg():
    def __init__(self,bot):
        self.bot = bot

    async def get_info(self):
        urlForInfo = await aiohttp.get("https://pubg.op.gg/user/"+user_info[0])
        urlForInfo = await urlForInfo.text()
        # urlForInfo = urllib.request.urlopen("https://pubg.op.gg/user/"+user[0]).read()
        soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(urlForInfo, "lxml")
        info = soup.find("div",{"class":"player-summary__name"})
        playerID = info["data-user_id"]
        playerNickname = info["data-user_nickname"]
        season = soup.find("button",{"class":"ranked-stats-wrapper__season-btn"})
        currentSeason = season["data-season"]
        return playerID, playerNickname, currentSeason

    async def get_kd(self):
        playerID, playerNickname, currentSeason = self.get_info()
        url = "https://pubg.op.gg/api/users/{}/ranked-stats?season={}&server={}&queue_size={}&mode={}".format(playerID,currentSeason,user[3],user[1],user[2])
        resp = requests.get(url).text
        resp = json.loads(resp)
        """ Player Game Stats """
        kills = resp["stats"]["kills_sum"]
        deaths = resp["stats"]["deaths_sum"]

        killDeath = str(kills / deaths)
        KD = killDeath[:4]
        return KD

    @commands.command(pass_context = True)
    async def kd(self, ctx):
        KD = self.get_kd()
        user_info = ctx.message.content.replace(".kd", "")
        user = user_info.split("-")
        await self.bot.say(f"Your K/D is: {KD}")
        #await self.bot.say("test")

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Pubg(bot))
```

Comment: Take a closer look at `KD = self.get_kd()`.

Comment: `get_info` and `get_kd` are coroutines. You can't just call them, you also need to await them. `KD = await self.get_kd()` and `playerID, playerNickname, currentSession = await self.get_info()`

Comment: @dirn that makes sense, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Always for coroutines you need `await`. You forgot this in two places as you got `async definitions`.

So this code should now work (if this was the only problem):

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio,aiohttp,json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

class Pubg():
    def __init__(self,bot):
        self.bot = bot

    async def get_info(self):
        urlForInfo = await aiohttp.get("https://pubg.op.gg/user/"+user_info[0])
        urlForInfo = await urlForInfo.text()
        # urlForInfo = urllib.request.urlopen("https://pubg.op.gg/user/"+user[0]).read()
        soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(urlForInfo, "lxml")
        info = soup.find("div",{"class":"player-summary__name"})
        playerID = info["data-user_id"]
        playerNickname = info["data-user_nickname"]
        season = soup.find("button",{"class":"ranked-stats-wrapper__season-btn"})
        currentSeason = season["data-season"]
        return playerID, playerNickname, currentSeason

    async def get_kd(self):
        playerID, playerNickname, currentSeason = await self.get_info()
        url = "https://pubg.op.gg/api/users/{}/ranked-stats?season={}&server={}&queue_size={}&mode={}".format(playerID,currentSeason,user[3],user[1],user[2])
        resp = requests.get(url).text
        resp = json.loads(resp)
        """ Player Game Stats """
        kills = resp["stats"]["kills_sum"]
        deaths = resp["stats"]["deaths_sum"]

        killDeath = str(kills / deaths)
        KD = killDeath[:4]
        return KD

    @commands.command(pass_context = True)
    async def kd(self, ctx):
        KD = await self.get_kd()
        user_info = ctx.message.content.replace(".kd", "")
        user = user_info.split("-")
        await self.bot.say(f"Your K/D is: {KD}")
        #await self.bot.say("test")

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Pubg(bot))
```

Answer (score -2):

If you do a couroutine, so a function with async, every return must be "await return"